# De facto standard width of a business computer

Tags: history

A very interesting article about an interesting, late (in more senses than one) and little remembered computer:
https://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/06/28/30_years_on_the_story_of_the_memotech_mtx/?page=3

says this:

> Coming as the MTX did from the SM1, it was decided very early on that it would measure up to the de facto standard width of a business computer, 475mm, and that it would be clad in Memotech’s trademark black anodised aluminium. The extra numeric keypad and function keys were added because the Qwerty deck alone looked lost among the acres of metal.

I never heard of a de facto standard width of a business computer before. Where did that come from?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the MTX didn’t connect to the FDX “via RS232”.
It connected through an expansion card that had the bus interface chips and also RS232 chips (which were usually populated).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I never heard of a de facto standard width of a business computer before.

No there wasn't one. Beside the  fact that defacto is quite vague if not said in conjunction with a specific example, there was no generally adopted. Especially not in 1983, when everyone was still making different machines with much differing features. The fact alone that Memotech did design their own layout does show that there wasn't a conform standard to follow.

> Where did that come from?

Most likely it's an euphemism to avoid saying 'IBM', as the PC/AT Keyboard did measure 47.5 cm (PC/XT was 45.5).

---

Many nice (read more than just the typewriter field) computer keyboards ranged between 40 and 55cm. Thus computer furniture is made to accomplish these sizes. Building a keyboard at or slightly below 50 cm is therefore a good idea, so why not just take it from the emerging machine made by this three letter company.

Comment: Of course, it's worth noting that 475mm fits conveniently in an industry-standard 19" equipment rack (which has a 482mm opening size), which could be what's being referred to?

Comment: @Jules 19" wasn't as much a thing in 1983 than it is today. And it still is anything but a 'business' computer - aka  desktop/office machien.

Comment: @Raffzahn mini-computers were rack-sized well before the 80s (as I suspect you know well), and 19” racks have been standard in other contexts since the 20s. Even if they weren’t a direct factor in office computer design, they could have had an indirect influence (*e.g.* on acceptable motherboard sizes).

Comment: @StephenKitt Not realy. They where confined to rather specialy usage. Not realy **business** computers. And even a truely rack dedicated company like DEC did produce keyboards wider than 19" for some of their terminals. So, beside not relevant as a **business** standard for desktop, the width of keyboards where not even consdered important to them. Puting keyboards into racks is something thatonly came up in the late 1980s early 90s for rackmount PC who needed a local keyboard. Minis always worked with serial and all done was to plug in a serial line when needed - one terminal for many racks.

Comment: @Raffzahn I wasn’t referring to keyboards, just to the size of computers (as in the question).

Comment: @StephenKitt But the passage is about the Keyboard - after all, the MTX _is_ a Keyboardcomuter - Also worth noting that it isn't 475mm but (almost) 490 - just checked.

Comment: @Raffzahn perhaps I misunderstood, I read “I never heard of a de facto standard width of a business computer before. Where did that come from?” as referring to computers, not keyboards. The quoted article is about a keyboard, but it compares its size to a “de facto standard” for computers, not keyboards.

Comment: @StephenKitt The way it's writen it implies to me that its about the keyboard, as it's about the construction of a keayboard computer and all text before and after that sentence is about keyboard features, isn't it? Als, the IBM PC was 20", that's about 51 cm, not 47.5. I think it's useful to read it in context. Further they where making a keyboard computer, so why look at a case they didn't include anyway? The FDX/HDX was an optional thing. Not sure about the size, as I don't own one.

Comment: @raffzahn You are aware the MTX512 is not (only) a keyboard computer but extends to full AT form factor with disk drives and expansion box?

Comment: @tofro It's a keyboard computer, as everything is in the keyboard. FDX/HDX is an optional unit, connected via RS232 (!) to the computer. Neither AT form factor, not anywhere a part of the computer. The only floppy expansion direct connected was the SDX, which plugged into the expansion port on the left side, making the machine look a bit like a CPC.

Comment: @Raffzahn "19" wasn't as much a thing in 1983 than it is today" - um, how about rack-mount DEC PDPs, DG Novas? Also in the UK educational market - very much where Memotech wanted to compete - were the Acorn Eurocard systems (1980-1983) and the RM 380Z (1977-1985): both 19" rack mount.

Comment: @scruss How many DEC have you seen in a office - orclass room - to make it standard business computer? To qualify as a standard, it would mean a considerable share, wouldn't it? Can't see that for 19". 19" back then was rather exotic, not exactly mass marketed. I wouldn't wonder if Commodore's PET outold all DEC in 1983, so the PET as standard?

Comment: Astonishing that there wasn't 19" or 43.5 cm (HiFi) or something coming into force like: "we ned to stack that" or "X does it, so that's it". Is there really not more to this?